# How to ensure a C++ function is declared before being defined (like the override keyword)?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

In my shared library I declared a function in a header file, and defined it in a .cpp source file. When linking an application with the library, the linker complains that the function is undefined and I don't know whether it's because of a missing namespace, different parameters, or something else.

If I could mark the function definition as "implementing a previous declaration", I would catch this declaration/definition difference during compilation, instead of later when I link an app with the library.

Is there something similar to the "override" keyword for class methods that would prevent me from defining a function without an existing matching declaration ?

I could use `-Wl,--no-undefined` but some libraries were created with the expectation that `--no-undefined` will not be used.

Comment: Include the header in the source file is the first guess. And make sure the header has guards. All just guesses, though. No code. [mre] and [ask] are cited a ton for a reason.

Comment: Your unit tests not linking would be one indicator

Comment: For shared libraries on Linux read [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~sergey/cs258/ABI/UlrichDrepper-How-To-Write-Shared-Libraries.pdf). Read [Program Library HowTo](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and [C++ dlopen minihowto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Declare* a function in a header file in a namespace, e.g.:

```
namespace N { void f(); }
```

*Define* the function in a `.cc` file using a [*qualified* function name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Qualified_identifiers):

```
void N::f() { /*...*/ }
```

This way if no declaration of `f` in namespace `N` matches the definition, a compiler error is issued.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer by Maxim Egorushkin can be simplified as follows for some compilers:

Declare the function as normal in the header file:

```
void f();
```

Define the function using a qualified name with the unnamed namespace:

```
void ::f() { /* ... */ }
```

Obviously you can also place it in a namespace.

Comment: That cannot be simplified as you did: `error: explicit qualification in declaration of ‘void f()’`.

Comment: Works in Visual Studio 2017, clang 3.1, 3.5...10.0. 
Does not work in gcc.

Comment: It seems this changed to be legal in 2006.
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#482 but I am not a C++ language lawyer.

Comment: `clang` yields `warning: extra qualification on member 'f' [-Wextra-qualification]`. I do not see why that shouldn't work as expected, but that's what things are today and that's the reason I didn't mention it in my answer.